# unable to validate date

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to validate date which is in between 1996 & 1900 for date of birth field. And also it should be in correct date format

but this below function is giving me output always false. 
what i am doing wrong ?

```
 function validateDate($date) {
        $this->load->helper('date');
        $datestring1 = "%Y-%m-%d";
        $date1 = "1996-01-01";
          $date2 = "1990-01-01";
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
        return $d && $d->format('Y-m-d') == $date && $date > $date2 && $date < $date1;
    }
```

Comment: please consider writing comment while doing vote down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is wrong with your function but this should work

```
function validate($date){

    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);

    if($d === false) return false;

    $y = intval($d->format('Y'));

    return $y >= 1990 && $y < 1996;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but Still does not work.It is giving  "false" even if the date is correct eg. http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20140720-advb-19kb.jpg   in this case what could be the mistake?

Comment: you want date between 1990 and 1996. in screenshot you have entered 1988 :/ which should result in false only. @Sundara and for `PHP versions below 5.3.0` this answer **wont work**.

Comment: Yeah you are right.. actually my above code is also working.. It was for Date of Birth validation which should be between 1900 & 1996 but in my above code i have pointed wrong starting date i.e 1900.. & you helped me to remind this

Answer (score 0):

If you want 1988-07-25 to be a valid entry (as shown in your screenshot), your "date2" should be "1980" or something earlier instead of "1990".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function validation($date){ //yyyy-mm-dd
    $date_element = explode('-', $date);
    if(is_array($date_element) and isset($date_element[0]) and ($date_element[0] >= 1990 and $date_element[0] <= 1996)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```